# Actions and Expected result are disabled in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, tfs, case

I am trying to write my first test case using TFS 2010 in VS2010 However Actions and Expected results columns won't allow me to add those steps ... any thing am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/compare

The link is referring to Visual Studio 2012 editions, but it is nearly the same with 2010. This means that those steps can only be done in Microsoft Test Manager, which is part of Ultimate and Test Edition in 2010. In 2012 it is also available in Premium edition.

To solve your problem you need to install the correct edition and than use the Test Manager. There should be also a button in Visual Studio which says "Edit with Microsoft Test Manager".